# Travel Europe to Russia

Tags: air-travel, europe, russia, pakistani-citizens

I have a Italian work permit validity for 5 year with Pakistani passport so I want to spend my holidays in Russia so can I travel with out visa

Comment: No,  you cannot, you will need a visa.

Answer (score 3):

You need a visa.

Pakistani citizens need a visa (so I guess, didn't actually check) and having Italian work permit gives you nothing since even Italian citizens need a visa to enter Russia.